# "org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists" but it does exists

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm using hibernate for my web service.

I'm able to list all the records, but unable to get just one.

The table contains:

```
ID (VARCHAR)                      VALUE(BIT)
celiac                               1
rate                                 1
suggestions                          0
```

The error shown is:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.pfc.restaurante.models.Device#id="xxxxxx"]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

And the main code:

```
    @JsonAutoDetect
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "SETTINGS")
    public class Settings implements Serializable{
        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        private String id;

        @Column(name="VALUE", nullable=false)
        private boolean value;
    (...)
    }
    //////////////////7
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/settingsService")
   public class SettingsServiceController {

    @Autowired
    SettingsService settingsService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Settings find(@PathVariable("id") String id){
        return settingsService.find(id);
    }
          (...)
}
```

I've read around that it could be because DB incongruence with my entity (some nullable = true when it shouldn't), but I've checked it already and there is no such a thing.

Could someone lend me a hand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is your `Settings` class and the exception refers to `Device` class. Show us the true log (with true ID, and not `xxxxx`) , Device table and Device class.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. Nevertheless errors were the same for Device and Settings, and xxxx was a real test ID :). Solution above has been succesful thanks to Antonio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error refers to an entity named 'Device' but your code shows an entity 'Settings'. Are they the same?

I've seen this error only in 2 situations:

1. The main entity does not exist in the DB and Session.load() is used. Use Session.get() and check for null instead.
2. Broken relationships. Consider this: EntityA owns a relation to EntityB. EntityB is deleted while the FK in EntityA is left untouched. So, whenever HB tries to load the link A-B the error happens. This can happen when running a normal search or even when saving/refreshing EntityA (HB needs to refresh the link as well).

Comment: Indeed, they gave me same error. I'm sorry I've forgot to change the error.
Anyway, thank you! First solution was the right one. I was using session.load(). I've just changed it for session.get() and it works ok now.